# Firefox Extension: Execute action when user closes the browser

Tags: firefox-addon

I have an extension with a sidebar, when the user close the sidebar a method is called.
I need to diference when the user close the sidebar than when he closes the browser.

pseudo code:

```
if (userClosedBrowser){
 //do something
}else if(userClosedSidebar){
 //do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for the "quit-application" observer topic.  Or, if you want to be able to stop the quit, you can listen for "quit-application-requested".

Comment: That's what I need, can you give me an example of it? because on MDC I can't understand it at all.

Comment: Basically, you need to add an observer like this (http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/components/passwordmgr/src/nsLoginManagerPrompter.js#55), and then add a method called observe like this (http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/components/passwordmgr/src/nsLoginManagerPrompter.js#69).  This page (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_School/Observer_Notifications) on MDC should give a good explanation.